# How do I, at the scene level, find the id of label and button nodes clicked in my scene?

Tags: javafx

*My setup*

I have added an `EventFilter` to an `Hbox` node which also contains two VBoxes.

In one of the VBoxes I have a `Button`, a `Label`, and a `TextArea` class instance.

The `EventHandler` is:

```
public static EventHandler<MouseEvent> pageEventFilter = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
     @Override 
     public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        EventTarget target = e.getTarget();
        String name = target.getClass().getName();
        System.out.println("NAME: " + name);
     } 
  };
```

In the event filter, I want to get the id string for buttons or labels that the user clicks on.

*I cannot determine the button or label clicked*

When I click on a part of the button or label, I get the following class names reported:

- click on button text ->

  - `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LabeledText`
- click outside button text ->

  - `javafx.scene.control.Button` or `javafx.scene.control.Label`

Trying to cast the event target of `LabeledText` to a `Button` or a `Label` gives me a `ClassCastException`.

If I try to create a variable:

```
LabeledText lbt = target
```

I get a compilation error that the `LabeledText` class does not exist.

*Similarly for `TextArea`*

When I click on the `TextArea`, I get  `javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin$ContentView` as the name of the target class. I am unable to click anywhere to get `TextArea` reported as the event target class. When I click the text in the TextArea, I get `javafx.scene.text.Text`, I cannot get the `id` of the `TextArea` node from either of these.

*My Question*

How do I find the parent of the target node, for the types of nodes I am interested in (buttons, labels and perhaps some other types), for which I can then get the node ID string using:

```
String nodeId = targetParentNode.getId();
```

Comment: Study the [event handling tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/index.html).  If you understand it, you should understand what is happening, what is wrong with your approach, why it is fundamentally flawed, and how to fix it (one way would be to add filters to each of the nodes you want to be able to intercept events for).

Comment: The reason why the target is not what you think it is, is because controls are made up of multiple nodes internally. For instance, the default `Label` uses a `Text` instance to actually display text. If you click on the `Text` then that's the target of the mouse event. That typically doesn't matter, because you'd have added the event filter/handler to the `Label` itself.

Comment: I have read the jewelsea and slaw comments above and I completely understand what you are saying. Is there ANY way, method or means, that I can get the value of the id property I assigned to the Label, Button, or TextArea to which these sub structures belong?

Comment: @jewelsea, regarding your solution, "(one way would be to add filters to each of the nodes you want to be able to intercept events for", I would PREFER using an EventFilter assigned to the parent node of multiple buttons, labels, and textareas and process the click event on any of them when they bubble up to the node. Do  you know of a way to determine which button or label belongs to LabeledText instance when received by the parent node that has the EventFilter added?

Comment: "Do you know of a way to determine which button or label belongs to LabeledText instance when received by the parent node that has the EventFilter added?" -> You could keep calling [node.getParent()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getParent()) on the target and the parent of the target, etc until you find (or don't find) something you are interested in.  Might work in your case, perhaps check the type of each node as you go up the hierarchy.

Comment: And most sentences (like this one) don't need to start with and.  (And when) references are made to types like `Button`, they can be enclosed in back ticks instead of double quotes.  Large pieces of text can be separated to paragraphs, or use bullet points or numbering, or have interspersed code blocks, and it will be easier to read.  Just a few orthogonal syle points.

Comment: Thanks @jewelsea, the problem with calling node.getParent() on the target is that symbol getParent() is not found. I have found the source code for the LabeledText class and examining its properties and methods reveals nothing usable to determine what control, button or label, it belongs to.  So it looks like javafx may not offer a solution I need and I will be forced to follow your suggestion of using one event handler but I have to assign it to probably every or nearly every control to avoid getting these contained classes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I reformatted your question based on the style pointers I provided in the previous comment.  If the reformatting misrepresents your intention or you prefer the original, please roll the edit back.  I think this was an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info).  Perhaps the question title should have been "How do I, at the scene level, find the id of label and button nodes clicked in my scene?"

Comment: All nodes have a getParent() function.  Anything in the scene graph is a node (including LabeledText), which is a com.sun class which is why it is not visible in a modular app and you should not be using in any case because it is not public API.  The target of any mouse event on the scene will be a node.  So you can find the parent node of the target node use `((Node) target).getParent()`.  So a simple while loop looking up the parent chain will get a result.  I'll see if I can put together a demo for you.

Comment: Why do you want to know the ids?

Comment: Thanks for all the above @jewelsea. Why I want to get node ids:  I am creating a program that allows user to create Pane, Control, and Shape nodes in a Scene's Pane node. Like the "Scene Builder", I provide a TreeView control that maintains a tree structure corresponding to the Scene Graph the user creates. Unlike "Scene Builder", I assign unique id's using  node short name "VBox" + unique integer "1" = "VBox1", etc. I want user to be able to "highlight" a node he wants to edit by clicking on the node in the scene graph OR on a node in the TreeView graph. The node can then be target of edits.

Comment: @jewelsea, The user can then save his work in JSON format for later recreation and display exactly as designed. He thus is able to create javafx "GUI documents" which can be anywhere from quite easy and simple like a "multimedia scratch pad" (MS OneNote or EvernNote) or more complex and artistic like PDF, PowerPoint, or HTML presentations.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. It helps explain the reason for your request. When you have a lot of additional info to add, it is best to edit the question and put the info there instead of in comments.  Good luck with your app.

Comment: Gluon provide the source for SceneBuilder and a build of it called SceneBuilder kit, which is separated from the SceneBuilder application.  You might want to research at the Gluon site and review the kit and source to see if there are either and ideas or code or pre-built modules or SDKs which might help you with you application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot, the user has clicked on a descendent node of a TextArea which is of type ContentView.

On intercepting the click event in a filter, the application has walked up the scene graph branch via repeated `getParent()` calls until it has found a higher level node of one of the specified types.  In this case it has found a TextArea.  It has then queried that text area for its "id" value and reported it in the appropriate label.

[image: screenshot]

*IdReporterApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IdReporterApp extends Application {

    private static final String CSS =
            """
            data:text/css,
            .label {
                -fx-padding: 3px;
                -fx-background-color: lightblue;
            }
            
            VBox {
                -fx-spacing: 10px;
                -fx-padding: 10px;
                -fx-background-color: lemonchiffon;
            }
            
            HBox {
                -fx-padding: 10px;
                -fx-background-color: palegreen;
            }
            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new IdController().getUI());
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*IdController.java*

```
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.util.List;

class IdController {
    private final Label clickedTargetTypeLabel = new Label();
    private final Label reportedTargetTypeLabel = new Label();
    private final Label reportedTargetIdLabel = new Label();

    private final EventTargetFinder eventTargetFinder = new EventTargetFinder(
            List.of(
                    Label.class, Button.class, TextArea.class
            )
    );

    public Parent getUI() {
        final VBox layout = new VBox(
                new VBox(
                        id("box1", new Label("Box 1")),
                        id("button1", new Button("Button"))
                ),
                new VBox(
                        id("box2", new Label("Box 2")),
                        id("textArea1", new TextArea("Text Area"))
                ),
                new HBox(
                        id("clickTargetLabel", new Label("Clicked target Type")),
                        id( "clickTargetValueLabel", clickedTargetTypeLabel)
                ),
                new HBox(
                        id("reportedTargetLabel", new Label("Reported target Type")),
                        id( "reportedTargetTypeLabel", reportedTargetTypeLabel)
                ),
                new HBox(
                        id("reportedTargetIdLabel", new Label("Reported target ID")),
                        id("reportedTargetIdValueLabel", reportedTargetIdLabel)
                )
        );

        layout.addEventFilter(
                MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                this::updateTargetLabels
        );
        
        return layout;
    }

    private Node id(String id, Node node) {
        node.setId(id);

        return node;
    }

    private void updateTargetLabels(MouseEvent e) {
        EventTargetFinder.TargetSearchResult searchResult =
                eventTargetFinder.findTargetsForMouseEvent(e);

        clickedTargetTypeLabel.setText(
                searchResult
                        .clickedTarget()
                        .getClass()
                        .getSimpleName()
        );

        reportedTargetTypeLabel.setText(
                searchResult.reportedTarget() == null
                        ? "null"
                        : searchResult
                                .reportedTarget()
                                .getClass()
                                .getSimpleName()
        );

        reportedTargetIdLabel.setText(
                searchResult.reportedTarget() == null
                        ? "none"
                        : searchResult.reportedTarget().getId() == null
                                ? "null"
                                : searchResult.reportedTarget().getId()

        );
    }
}
```

*EventTargetFinder.java*

```
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

record EventTargetFinder(List<Class<? extends Node>> filterTargetTypes) {
    EventTargetFinder(List<Class<? extends Node>> filterTargetTypes) {
        this.filterTargetTypes = Collections.unmodifiableList(filterTargetTypes);
    }

    record TargetSearchResult(
            Node clickedTarget,
            Node reportedTarget
    ) {}

    public TargetSearchResult findTargetsForMouseEvent(MouseEvent event) {
        Node target = (Node) event.getTarget();

        Node clickedTarget = target;

        while (target != null && !isTargetFiltered(target)) {
            target = target.getParent();
        }

        Node reportedTarget = target;

        return new TargetSearchResult(clickedTarget, reportedTarget);
    }

    private boolean isTargetFiltered(Node target) {
        return filterTargetTypes.stream()
                .anyMatch(
                        t -> t.isInstance(target)
                );
    }
}
```